# How can I read a 2-columns CSV file into a map with ranges?

Tags: c++, functional-programming, c++20, range-v3, std-ranges

I'm given a CSV file with two elements per line:

```
1,2
12,40
11,7
...
```

which I want to read into a `std::map<int, int>`.

How can I do that, using anything from [Ranges library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges) and [Range-v3](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/index.html)?

At the moment this is where I've got (with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59516999/5825294)):

```cpp
#include <boost/hof/lift.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <range/v3/istream_range.hpp>
#include <range/v3/range/conversion.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/istream.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/join.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/chunk.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/transform.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/split.hpp>
#include <string>

using ranges::istream;
using ranges::to;
using namespace ranges::views;

constexpr auto splitAtComma = [](auto const& r) { return r | split(','); };
constexpr auto rngToString = [](auto const& r) { return r | to<std::string>; };
constexpr auto strToInt = BOOST_HOF_LIFT(std::stoi);

constexpr auto parseCoords = transform(splitAtComma)
                           | join
                           | transform(rngToString)
                           | transform(strToInt)
                           | chunk(2);
int main() {

    auto lines = istream<std::string>(std::cin);

    auto coords = lines | parseCoords;

    std::cout << coords << std::endl;
}
```

which, invoked like this

```bash
./main <<END
1,2
12,40
11,7
END
```

gives this output

```
[[1,2],[12,40],[11,7]]
```

The point is that now I don't know how convert that range-of-ranges into a map. Also, I have the feeling that I'm in a dead-end street, because each element of a `std::map<int, int>` comes from 2 `int`s, but in the range-of-ranges above `[1,2]`, `[12,40]`, and `[11,7]` are just ranges of `int`s, not encoding at compile tiime that there's 2 `int`s only.

Comment: "*but in the range-of-ranges above `[1,2]`, `[12,40]`, and `[11,7]` are just ranges of ints, not encoding at compile tiime that there's 2 ints only.* But you *already* know they only have 2 elements, don't you?

Comment: @康桓瑋, I do, because the `2` in `chunk(2)` is a know compile-time literal. But that's not enough for something like `| transform(to<std::pair>)` to work on it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use `join` here because `r | split(',')` already gives you a range with two elements. Prefer `std::from_chars` over `std::stoi`.

You can do this only using the standard library's `<ranges>`

```
#include <ranges>
#include <charconv>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
#include <sstream>

auto toInt = [](auto r) {
  int i = 0;
  std::from_chars(std::to_address(r.begin()), std::to_address(r.end()), i);
  return i;
};

auto parseCoords = 
  std::views::transform(
    [](auto r) { return std::move(r) | std::views::split(','); })
| std::views::transform(
    [](auto r) { return std::pair{toInt(r.front()), toInt(*++r.begin())}; });

int main() {
  auto in = std::istringstream{R"(
1,2
12,40
11,7
)"};
  auto coords = std::views::istream<std::string>(in)
              | parseCoords;
  fmt::print("{}\n", coords);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nvr6TTfz3)

Note that the `std::move(r)` in `views::transform` is necessary because we need to construct an `owning_view` to avoid the dangling issue.

Comment: But `coords` is not yet a `std::map`, is it?

Comment: Just simply use [`ranges::to`](https://eel.is/c++draft/range.utility.conv). [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rP51Ps77z).