# What is an istream_view and when do I use one?

Tags: c++, range, c++20, istream, istream-view

Apparently, C++20 has a new `std::istream`-related construct: `std::istream_view`. The [cppreference page on it](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/basic_istream_view) is a stub right now<sup>†</sup>. So, what is a "view of an `istream`" and what can I use it for?

---

<sub>† - Ok, technically it redirects to a page about `std::basic_istream_view` and *that one*'s a stub.</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `std::istream_view<T>` is a **range**; and more specifically, a range formed as a **view**. This addition to the standard library is akin to what you might find under `std::ranges::views` - except that it's not a view of an arbitrary range, but of an `std::istream`.

So what "viewing" is applied to an `std::istream`? Recall an `istream` is a stream of *characters*, not of arbitrary *`T`*-type elements of your choice. The lazy application of parsing those characters into consecutive `T`'s is the "viewing" of the the istream. That is, the k'th element of `std::istream_view<T>(is)` is what you'd get the k'th time running `is >> t` for `t` of type `T`.

You would use an `std::istream_view` ([carefully](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue3408)) when you want to apply your code, which works with ranges, directly to input data - rather than first parsing your input into some data structure in a more "old-school" manner, then working on that structure as a range.

Other takes on what an `std::istream_view` is:

- @Barry has described it as the equivalent of a coroutine which parses `T`s from an istream; read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59147939/1593077) for details (note it's about the istream view in the ranges-v3, much of which became the standard ranges library).
- @NicolBolas considers it to be the result of "wrapping   `std::istream_iterator<T>` in a C++20 view interface".

Comment: So it's just an `istream_iterator<T>` wrapped in a C++20 view interface.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Is it really just  the pair of `std::istream_iterator<T>(my_istream)` and `std::istream_iterator<T>()`?

Comment: I doubt its using exactly those types, since I'm not sure if they count as conceptualized iterators. But what you described is the basic idea.

Comment: @Barry: I was mistakenly assumign that switching element type makes it a non-view. Edited.

Comment: @NicolBolas You can think of it as that, except more efficient. `istream_iterator<T>` has to have a `T` member, which means copying that iterator has to copy the `T`. Here, `istream_view<T>` is the one with the `T` member while `istream_view<T>::iterator` just has an `istream_view<T>*`, so the iterators are cheaper to copy.

Comment: We don't often copy iterators, though.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings so you take your iterators by `&`? Why? I find most (if not all) people copying iterators all over the place. Call a `all_of` that does some `find_if`ing and you are having N^2 number of copies. You don't use `<algorithm>`? All of these stuff copies iterators.

Comment: @Fureeish Did I say never? Did I say I pass iterators by address? No... Let's avoid strawman arguments. How often do you do `all_of` with `find_if` inside? Your typical use case is like `std::find(begin, end, val)` and that's a couple of copies. Not nothing, sure, but is this really a massive deal?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Did **I** say never? What's left if you don't copy them when passing? Combining `all_of` with `find_if` is common enough for people I've worked with (size of the company varied) to mention it. "Couple of copies" per use case is enough to consider "not often copying iterators" a mistake. Not to mention all the generic code that works on iterators and delegates work to other parts where they get copied *again*. So yeah, it is kind of a massive deal to make iterators as small as possible, simply because it's an established C++ convention that iterators are cheap to copy.

Comment: @Fureeish And a `char` _is_ cheap to copy. Like, _very_. I'm hearing a lot of assertions that "this is bad", but no actual data or solid convincing arguments on _why_ this is bad. I'd wager it took you longer to write your last comment than you'd ever have saved on copying `char`s stored in `istream_iterator`s.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWIngs the thing with abstracting away the concept of iterators is that *all* iterators to be cheap to copy. In that case, one should care about them meeting those requirements. `char` is *always* cheap to copy, so you don't have to argue about that. When you compare `char`s to `iterator`s you say that "`char`s are very cheap to copy". Great. If we rely on `char`s being cheap to copy, we can as well rely on all `iterator`s being cheap to copy.

Being conditionally cheap to copy (whether an iterator holds `char` or `string`) would defeat a lof of freedom of optimisations.

Comment: @Fureeish More strawmen! Nobody's talking about some other kind of iterator. We're talking about istream iterators. That's it. End of story. So those are `char` or, maybe, `wchar_t` which can be four bytes. Hardly taxing for your computer. You are still not really providing any evidence of a real, practical problem here. The point is that this istream_view does _not_, as far as I can see, offer any substantial performance benefits, contrary to some claims above. If you disagree, feel free to provide some _practical_ evidence!

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings ehh... I am providing a generic view on iterator usability... Not storing a variable inside an iterator is obviously better for space then actually storing it.

Comment: @Fureeish There's nothing "obvious" about that claim at all. Regardless, it seems you're talking about something unrelated to the topic of this Q&A, so let's move on.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: Without taking sides here - don't istream iterators keep a `T` value, rather than a `char` or `wchar_t`?

Comment: @einpoklum Oh, well that's a good point - I guess I was thinking more of `istreambuf_iterator` then!

Comment: More to the point - is this discussion supposed to result in an edit or a recommendation of an edit? :-\